# Issue when trying to receive JSON array response using OkHTTP, PHP, and MySQL in Android

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, okhttp

I'm having trouble receving a JSON array response from my server in my Android Application.  Currently, my PHP code is as follows:

```
    $con = $this->connect_to_db();
    $data = array($userID);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT AccountName, AccountAmount FROM Account WHERE User_idUser = ?;");
    $res = $stmt->execute($data);

    echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

When echoing to another php file that I call through the command line, I get the whole response correctly, which is (in pretty print):

```
[
{
    "AccountName": "POTATO",
    "AccountAmount": "12000.00"
},
{
    "AccountName": "SpartanSaver",
    "AccountAmount": "1200.00"
},
{
    "AccountName": "TestAccount",
    "AccountAmount": "12000.00"
}
]
```

However, in my android application, I only receive the word "Array" in the response body.  That code is:

```
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getAccountsUrl)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.i("RESPONSE", response.body().string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The output in Logcat from this is

```
I/RESPONSE﹕ Array
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why that is the only thing I'm receiving when the whole thing is returned when called by a test php file.  I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Hi, can you post your json string

Comment: This is what I get when calling it when a test php file:


    [
    {
        "AccountName": "POTATO",
        "AccountAmount": "12000.00"
    },
    {
        "AccountName": "SpartanSaver",
        "AccountAmount": "1200.00"
    },
    {
        "AccountName": "TestAccount",
        "AccountAmount": "12000.00"
    }
]